# binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double?' and 'Double'

Tags: ios, swift, binary, double, operators

I'm new to Swift and have searched some through the answers I've seen on this, but am trying to find out how to correct this problem. I have a Swift playground with code that runs fine and does not return this error, but have similar code in an iOS project that does return this error. It occurs when I'm comparing a fibers counted value to 5.5.

The only difference I can see between the 2 situations is the playground code is not using a user input from a text field where I convert the text to a Double. I input a fibers counted value, and all appears to be ok.

However, in the iOS project, I get the error message above, and don't understand how to fix it, and most importantly, why I have an error in one code set but not the other. It seems I'd either get it to work in both instances or not at all. Thanks in advance.

This code runs ok:

```
var ECA: Double
var FibersCounted: Double
var FieldsCounted: Double
var FieldArea: Double
var SampleVolume: Double
var ResultNumerator: Double
var ResultDenominator: Double
var SampleResult: Double
var SampleLimitofDetection: Double

ECA = 385
FibersCounted = 65
FieldsCounted = 100
FieldArea = 0.00785
SampleVolume = 1200

if FibersCounted <= 5.5 {
    ResultNumerator = (ECA * (5.5 / 100))
    ResultDenominator = (FieldArea * SampleVolume * 1000)
    SampleResult = ResultNumerator / ResultDenominator
    } else {
    ResultNumerator = (ECA * (FibersCounted / FieldsCounted))
    ResultDenominator = (FieldArea * SampleVolume * 1000)
    SampleResult = ResultNumerator / ResultDenominator
}
```

This code returns the error message when fibersCounted is compared to 5.5 (i.e. "if fibersCounted < 5.5 {" line triggers the error:

```
@IBOutlet weak var sampleVolumeTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var numberFibersCountedTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var numberBlankFibersCountedTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var numberFieldsCountedTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var fiberDensityLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var limitOfDetectionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var sampleResultLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func calculatePressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let sampleVolume = Double(sampleVolumeTextField.text!)

        let fibersCounted = Double(numberFibersCountedTextField.text!)

        let numberBlankFibersCounted = Double(numberBlankFibersCountedTextField.text!)

        let fieldsCounted = Double(numberFieldsCountedTextField.text!)

        var resultNumerator: Double

        var resultDenominator: Double

        var sampleResult: Double

        var sampleLimitofDetection: Double

        //calculate sample result based on actual fiber count or 5.5 fiber LOD value
        if fibersCounted < 5.5 {
            resultNumerator = (385 * (5.5 / 100))
            resultDenominator = (7.85 * sampleVolume!)
            let sampleResult = resultNumerator / resultDenominator
        } else {
            resultNumerator = (385 * (fibersCounted! / fieldsCounted!))
            resultDenominator = (7.85 * sampleVolume!)
            let sampleResult = resultNumerator / resultDenominator
        }
```

Comment: hey everyone, thank you so much for taking the time to read and reply with advice. I'm going to look at each answer, then see what works. I'll get back and let you all know. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: ok - so I was able to use "if let..." to get it to work. Thanks again everyone for all your help. I'll also work on improving wrapping/unwrapping syntax. Thanks for suggestions on all that as well.

Answer (score 4):

the best way how to do it without optional binding is to return `Double.nan` if `Double.init?( _: String)` failed. As mentioned by @LeoDabus using `.nan` is the right Swifty way and preferred.

```
let a = Double("1.122") ?? .nan
let b = Double("a.123") ?? .nan
let c = 1.123

a < c // true
b < c // false
a > c // false
b > c // false
```

this will always fail

```
b == b
```

Your code will be more readable and you don't need force unwrap double values anymore as you did a lot in you next calculations, which is potentially very dangerous in a real usage scenario.

Answer (score 0):

from documentation [init?(_ text: String)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/double/1538328-init) return optional type. So you need to unwrap it before comparing.
`if let fibersCounted = fibersCounted, fibersCounted < 5.5 {} else {}` should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Please check values is available or not in fieldsCounted.

```
if let count = fieldsCounted{
 if count < 5.5 {
        resultNumerator = (385 * (5.5 / 100))
        resultDenominator = (7.85 * sampleVolume!)
        let sampleResult = resultNumerator / resultDenominator
 }else{ 
        resultNumerator = (385 * (fibersCounted! / fieldsCounted!))
        resultDenominator = (7.85 * sampleVolume!)
        let sampleResult = resultNumerator / resultDenominator
 }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little new to swift as well but from the looks of it, you're comparing an optional double to a double. Try `if let fibersCounted = fibersCounted { with the code you want to execute }` to unwrap the value inside.